# I have a express app with socket.io but when I get like 70 concurrent connections the site doesn't send response

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

After 70-80 connections my nodejs doesn't send response back to user

```
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
socketIo.on('connection',async(socket) => {
    socket.handshake.session.save((err)=> {if(err)return err;});
    socketIo.emit('site online', Object.keys(socketIo.sockets.sockets).length)
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        socketIo.emit('site online', Object.keys(socketIo.sockets.sockets).length)
    })
    await UserController(<any>socket)
})
app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/public/index.html`)
})
```

and the Usercontroller is a promise that resolves when user disconnects

Answer (score 0):

the listener for disconnect is created always when a new connection is established.

```
socketIo.on('connection',async(socket) => {
    socket.handshake.session.save((err)=> {if(err)return err;});
    socketIo.emit('site online', Object.keys(socketIo.sockets.sockets).length)
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {  <--- Created everytime 'connection' event received
        socketIo.emit('site online', Object.keys(socketIo.sockets.sockets).length)
    })
    await UserController(<any>socket)
})
```

The listener should be created outside of the other listener:

```
socketIo.on('connection',async(socket) => {
   socket.handshake.session.save((err)=> {if(err)return err;});
   socketIo.emit('site online', Object.keys(socketIo.sockets.sockets).length)        
   await UserController(<any>socket)
})
socket.on('disconnect', () => { 
   socketIo.emit('site online', Object.keys(socketIo.sockets.sockets).length)
})
```

It all happens asynchroous, so you just create the 2 listeners in parallel. With your code, if you have 80 connections, you also have 80 disconnect listeners. That i guess can cause some problems.